# multithread SQL-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading

I have a SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO logins (name, password,roleId,email,phone)
    SELECT  'login', 'password', 1, 'mail@gmail.com', '375291234567'
    FROM (SELECT count(*) FROM logins as l4) as l3
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM logins as l2
        WHERE l2.name='login')
```

If I execute it in different threads with the same parameters, is it likely that there will be added 2 (or more) records? If it's true, so how can I block it?

I need a multiserver answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiserver answer" exactly how is your information distibuted, i.e the stucture of your farm?

Comment: The SOP way to address this is to make [name] a Primary Key on the [logins] table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Merge statement instead of insert. Then you will always have only one entry.
Check link at this details: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Comment: Note that `MERGE` is not atomic without appropriate locking.  See [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).